# How to use empty username/password/domain in vpn connection in windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I've created new VPN connection in Windows 8. Username, password and domain should be empty. That worked in Windows 7. But in Windows 8 Pro I have error "Please enter username and password".

How to force Windows 8 to connect using blank username and password?

Comment: you realize how utterly insecure and pointless a vpn with absolutely no authentication is?

Comment: @SnakeDoc they require static ip address and allow vpn only for certain ip-address. i just realized that any username and password will work, not necessary blank, so this is not a problem anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not such a stupid questions. With full name and password I still need to leave the domain blank (or the connection will fail). But Windows 8 'helpfully' copies the last part of user name (following the @) and uses it as the domain name with no possibility of editing it! How can one leave the domain blank? The part of the connection setup process that allowed you to do it in Windows 7 is skipped in Windows 8, and the 'properties' window does not contain that information.